# Using custom login page to login to liferay using Google Id

Tags: oauth, liferay, google-openid

We are developing a portal on liferay, where in user should be able to login to liferay using their Google Id.

Here we have to provide a custom login page for the users, which authenticates the users using the Google ID. But nowhere i could find a solution as to how to use google Id to log into Liferay. Could anyone please help me on this?

Answer (score 0):

Google does OpenID, right? You can just enable OpenID in Liferay - when you enter your google-openID identity, you'll be forwarded to google to authenticate.

ControlPanel/Portal Settings/Authentication/OpenID has the checkbox.

To make it a bit more comfortable (e.g. directly redirect to google or offer buttons with standard OpenId providers, like on stackoverflow.com) you might want to customize the Sign In Portlet, but as you specifically asked how to enable this feature - this is it.